# How to post one to many relation data in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern

We have 3 models `Category`, `Post` and `PostCategory`. I want to create Post method for Post and their category using a repository pattern so how to implement it.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public ICollection<PostCategory> PostCategories { get; set; }
}

public class PostCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int PostsId { get; set; }
    public Posts Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Posts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
  
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public Published IsPublished { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostCategory> PostCategories { get; set; }=new HashSet<PostCategory>();
}
```

So how to create the API?

Comment: You had trouble to query the data from the database? Or you had trouble to return data? Or something else?

Comment: I want to save post data with selected categories

Comment: store data into the database? If so, could you pls let us know what database you are using and what ORM framework you are using?

Comment: yes use entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

Each post is related to a list of `Categories` so the request object should looks like below:

```
 public class PostInputModel
 {
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<int> Categories { get; set; }
 }
```

If you are using `Entity-Framework` you should configure these relation properly. If you don't tell me this on comments.

So in your `Controller` or `ServiceLayer` you should match all categories:

```
 // You can write a separated method for your repository.
 var categories = _categoryRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(P => postInputModel.Categories.Contain(P.Id)).ToList();

 var post = new Post()
 {
      Title = postInputModel.Title,
      Description = postInputModel.Description,
      ImageUrl = postInputModel.ImageUrl,

      CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
      PostCategories = categories.Select(P => new PostCategory()
      { 
         Category = P
      }
 }
```

and you can save using `_context.SaveChange()` or whatever your using to do this.

What happens here is that, `Entity-Framework` will automatically detects that `PostCategory` is related to the `Posts` so in `PostCategory` it automatically fills `Posts`.
On the other side there is a one-to-many relation between `Category` and `PostCategory` this relation is applied.